# I can't understand this sentence

Tags: meaning, understanding

I could have picked up a dozen of those for next to nothing in the Cairo marketplace

Comment: It helps if you add more to your question.  Please explain what part of the sentence you don't understand, and if you have tried Google to help you with definitions?

Comment: i looked up the dictionary and know all the meanings respectively but whenever I try to construct the sentence, i just fail to understand

Comment: Which particular parts don't you understand? Cairo? dozen? or "picked up" and "next to nothing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the pieces:

> "to pick up" = "to buy"

So "I could have picked up" is the same as "I could have bought."

> "Next to nothing" = "very little money"

So "I bought [those] for next to nothing" = "I bought [those] for very little money".

I'm going to assume the rest of the sentence makes sense?  A dozen = 12, and I'm sure you know where is the "Cairo marketplace".

Putting it all together:

> I [could have picked up] [a dozen of those] [in the Cairo marketplace] [for next to nothing].
>
> I [could have bought] [twelve of those] [in the Cairo marketplace] [for very little money]